# Check Database for user existance

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying below code for checking user existance in database and echo result according to output.But i am getting "Fatal error: Method name must be a string in.............line".So, What's wrong in code. Any Suggestions?

```
<?php

$user_email="somthing@gmail.com";


try
{
    /*** connect to database ***/
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $mysql_hostname = '127.0.0.1';

    /*** mysql username ***/
    $mysql_username = 'root';

    /*** mysql password ***/
    $mysql_password = '';

    /*** database name ***/
    $mysql_dbname = 'something';


    /*** select the users name from the database ***/
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username,     $mysql_password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}



if ($this->$dbh()) {
        // check if username or email already exists
        $query_check_user_email = $this->$dbh->prepare('SELECT user_email FROM users          WHERE user_email=:user_email');
                    $query_check_user_email->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email,     PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_email->execute();
        $result = $query_check_user_email->fetchAll();

        // if username or/and email find in the database
        // TODO: this is really awful!
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            echo "exists!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "non existant";
 }

 ?>
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Drop the line number please, and if possible the line raising the error.

Comment: Show us the whole exception message.

Comment: what is this? `if ($this->$dbh()) {`? just drop that if block

Comment: There is no $this in your world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dbh` must be used instead of `$this->dbh`:

```
if ($dbh) {
        // check if username or email already exists
        $query_check_user_email = $dbh->prepare('SELECT user_email FROM users    
                                                 WHERE user_email=:user_email');
        $query_check_user_email->bindValue(':user_email', 
                                           $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_email->execute();
        $result = $query_check_user_email->fetchAll();

        // if username or/and email find in the database
        // TODO: this is really awful!
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            echo "exists!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "non existant";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username,     $mysql_password);
```

This will be a variable in the scope of your php block/file/whatever. You don't actually set it as a member, because you are not in a class.

Second: `$this->$dbh()`.

You are not in the scope of a classes member method. There is no `$this` where your code is.

Try using simply: `$dbh`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = :email;");
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

btw i would prefer calling the table user instead of  users.